# Remove a recently checked-in version from Subversion Source Control

Tags: svn, version-control

Not sure if this is possible, but recently a large amount of data was checked into Subversion unknowingly. We would rather completely remove that data that was checked in. Our understanding is that with version control, once you commit something to the repository even if you "delete it" it is still there as an older version. Do we have any options?

Comment: The only way is to dump, filter, then load the data. Should be other questions like this with answers.

Answer (score -1):

There is an option, although it's a bit complicated (http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal):

> How do I completely remove a file from the repository's history?
>
> There are special cases where you might want to destroy all evidence
>   of a file or commit. (Perhaps somebody accidentally committed a
>   confidential document.) This isn't so easy, because Subversion is
>   deliberately designed to never lose information. Revisions are
>   immutable trees which build upon one another. Removing a revision from
>   history would cause a domino effect, creating chaos in all subsequent
>   revisions and possibly invalidating all working copies.
>
> The project has plans, however, to someday implement an svnadmin
>   obliterate command which would accomplish the task of permanently
>   deleting information. (See issue 516.)
>
> **In the meantime, your only recourse is to svnadmin dump your
>   repository, then pipe the dumpfile through svndumpfilter (excluding
>   the bad path) into an svnadmin load command.** See chapter 5 of the
>   Subversion book for details about this.
>
> An alternative approach is to replicate the repository with svnsync
>   after configuring path-based authorization rules that deny read access
>   to any paths that need to be filtered from history. Unlike
>   svndumpfilter, svnsync will automatically translate copy operations
>   with an unreadable source path into normal additions, which is useful
>   if history involving copy operations needs to be filtered.

Comment: svndumpfilter for removing **changeset**?! LOL, RTFM dude!

Comment: if the changeset does not affect other changes, he could simply `svnadmin dump` the revision history skipping the revision and load the dump to a new repo.